# Does Captain America have normal hair growth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

To begin with, Captain America was buried in ice for 70 years. So,along with all his metabolism, his hair growth seems to have been inhibited.

But even after being rescued, he has never kept a beard not even a stuble in the MCU...

Can he grow hairs or not?

If not, is it because of the serum or due to him being buried in ice for so long?

Keep the answers limited to MCU but any subtle answer from the comicsverse  with a good explanation may also be considered.

Comment: I think we're running out of questions.

Comment: A downvote? What for? It's a fair question,mate

Comment: Not from me...just a bit of a silly question.

Comment: i think this is good i dont know ive weve ever seen him shave. at least not in the movies

Comment: We've never seen him go to the toilet either but I don't see anyone asking why... probably because it's something we just assume happens off camera like shaving!

Comment: The people in the movies must be terribly sleep-deprived, because we [hardly ever](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187513/) see them get more than a few minutes sleep.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I've never seen Batman trim his fingernails... BATCOMPUTER! Pull up *ASK QUESTION*

Comment: I"m sorry I made that joke. My parents- they had fingernails when we went to that **ZORRO** movie, so many, many years ago...

Comment: Upvote...not because it's a good question, but because I've seen worse ones get upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes, Captain America can grow a beard. In a story arc written in 2013 (World War Z) when trapped in an alien dimension, he grew a blonde beard. Why his hair didn't grow during his suspended animation is anyone's guess, but I suspect it didn't occur to anyone that perhaps it should have.

[image]

- Apparently as long as there are razors available, Captain America prefers to keep a clean-shaven face. It also occurs to me that few people sign up to watch Captain America, icon of Justice, shave.
- Given his 1940s origin, it makes sense that he would since being clean-shaven was the uniform of the day for the well-dressed New Yorker of the period.

Comment: "I suspect it didn't occur to anyone that perhaps it should have." - suspended animation implies that metabolic processes have stopped or slowed to barely detectable levels, so it would not make sense for him to grow a beard.

Comment: @Nathan This is what i was asking but they thought it to be a silly question.